# The factors of a tetration plus an integer

Tags: recreational-mathematics, exponentiation, factoring, tetration, power-towers

There I was, just messing around with tetration, when I stumbled across this -

$(x^x +1)/(x+1)$ = integer (for odd integer values of x)

Playing some more with this it seems (not entirely sure as tetration quickly becomes to hard to compute) -

$({{{^n}^+}^1}x + 1)$/$(^nx + 1)$ --> Integer

(also for odd integer values of x)

I am aware of that this is to do with the factors of $x^x +1$ ,but can anyone give a full deeper visceral explanation to this? (If it is true - if not then tell me)

Thanks

Comment: Do you have examples, where you can show it works?

Comment: sure, i'll get some up

Comment: (3^3^3 +1)/(3^3+1) = 272342767321

Comment: (7^7+1)/(7+1) = 102943

Comment: (11^11 + 1)/(11 +1) = 23775972551

Comment: and obviously (n+1)/(1) = integer

Comment: Check some more for yourself if you want

Comment: I checked some in maple until it overflowed. It seems that (5^5^5+1)/(5^5+1), and so on with 7, 9 and 11 are all integers. $n=3$ overflows.

Comment: I've got it now. I'll write an answer.

Comment: No wait, I only proved $(x^x+1) \mid ({}^nx+1)$......

Answer (score 1):

We have the factorisation:
$$
x^{k}+1 = (x+1)(1-x+x^{2}-\cdots +x^{(k-1)})
$$
for any odd natural number $k$.

$^n x$ divides $^{n+1}x$, since they are both just a bunch of $x$-factors. So we can write $^{n+1}x = k\cdot{}^n x$ for some odd $k$ (since $^{n+1}x$ is odd, $k$ has to be odd). Then we can factorise:
$$
{}^{n+1}x + 1 
= x^{{}^nx} + 1
= x^{k\cdot ({}^{n-1}x)} + 1 \\
= ({}^n x)^k+1
= ({}^n x+1)\left(1-({}^n x)^{({}^n x)}+({}^n x)^{2({}^n x)}-\cdots +({}^n x)^{(k-1)({}^n x)}\right)
$$
which proves the result.

BONUS:

The factorisation we used is a variation of the following, which works for any $k$:
$$
x^{k}-1 = (x-1)(1+x+x^{2}+\cdots +x^{(k-1)})
$$
Therefore we can conclude by the same method as above that $({}^n x-1)$ divides $({}^{n+1}x - 1)$ for any $x$.

Comment: Where did you get the factorisation from - I've never seen it before.

Comment: Oops, I wrote it all wrong. I'll edit.

Comment: Have you edited it; I can't tell

Comment: Haha, yes I have. You can find it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Recognizable_patterns) under "Sum, odd exponent" with $E=x^m$, $F=1$.

Comment: @JakubSkop I finally proved it :)

Comment: Very nicely done @3@

Comment: @JakubSkop I added a bonus result.

Comment: On a completely unrelated note, I just realised that that bonus factorisation can be approximated by (x-1)/(1-x) for larger values of k, which is pretty neat, I guess. (if x is between 0 and 1 (but not 1))

Comment: But $\frac{x-1}{1-x}$ is just $-1$?

Comment: well, the second bracket is a geometric series, which can approximated for large values of k by 1/1-x and then multiplied by x-1 from the first bracket leaves you with x-1/1-x

Comment: but remeber, for large values of k, any number within 0 and 1 will approach 0, and so then take away the 1 and you get ~-1

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.